# Как проверять выбранные option у мультиселекта?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, select2

Есть мультиселект и скрытый блок. Требуется показывать блок, если выбран определённый option. И обратно скрывать его, если нужный option убрали из выборки.

Обхожу выбранные option и проверяю их на val. Но что-то не так работает... Если выбирать поочерёдно, то когда выбраны все три option, блок почему-то скрывается.

```js
jQuery('.js-select').on('change', function(){
  
  
  jQuery(this).find('option:selected').each(function(){ 
    if( jQuery(this).val() == "Второй"){
        jQuery('p').show();

    } else {
      jQuery('p').hide();
      }
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 150px;
}

p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-select" name="add-programm[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Первый">Первый</option>
  <option value="Второй">Второй</option>
  <option value="Третий">Третий</option>
</select>
<p>Скрытый блок</p>
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам остро необходим именно селект? Это же могут быть просто отдельные кнопки, если уже селект предоставляется в виде большого блока с опциями.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME уже всё на селектах сделано (. Да и вроде почти работает )

Answer (score 1):

Если параграф точно будет только один, можно добавить показывающий класс только на тех элементах, которые должны показать его. И при клике проверять на наличие класса у опции... так будет оптимальнее, чем в скрипте сравнивать со значением == строкой опции и в случае изменения - лезть в скрипт опять менять.

Так:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.boo', function(){
  $('#moo').hide();
  if( $(this).hasClass('show') ){
    $('#moo').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#moo {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select" name="add-programm[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option class="boo show">Первый</option>
  <option class="boo show">Второй</option>
  <option class="boo">Третий</option>
</select>

<p id="moo">1111</p>
```

А если параграфов будет много, можно и показывать нужный, в соответствии с кликнутым:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.boo', function(){
  const index = $('.boo').index(this);//получили номер кликнутого элемента
  $('.moo').hide();//сперва скрыли все параграфы
  $('.moo').eq(index).show();//по полученному номеру - показали нужный
});
```

```css
.moo {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select" name="add-programm[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option class="boo">Первый</option>
  <option class="boo">Второй</option>
  <option class="boo">Третий</option>
</select>

<p class="moo">1111</p>
<p class="moo">2222</p>
<p class="moo">3333</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.js-select').on('change', function(){
  if($(this.selectedOptions).is('[value="Второй"]')){
    $('p').show();
  }else{
    $('p').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 150px;
}

p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-select" name="add-programm[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Первый">Первый</option>
  <option value="Второй">Второй</option>
  <option value="Третий">Третий</option>
</select>
<p>Скрытый блок</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала в любом случае скроем элемент при изменении выбора

А потом покажем если среди выбранных есть необходимый(необходимые) элементы

```js
jQuery('.js-select').on('change', function() {
  jQuery('p').hide(); 
  jQuery(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
    if (this.value == "Второй")
        jQuery('p').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-select" name="add-programm[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Первый">Первый</option>
  <option value="Второй">Второй</option>
  <option value="Третий">Третий</option>
</select>
<p style="display:none">Скрытый блок</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверка очень простая - ищем option по jQuery селектору - `option:selected`, берем value `$option.val()` и проверяем : )

Например:

```js
const $block = $('p')

$('.js-select').on('change', function () {
  let $option = $(this).find(':selected')
  let method = $option.val()
  $block[method]()
})
```

```css
select {
  width: 150px;
}

p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="hide">Первый</option>
  <option value="show">Второй</option>
  <option value="hide">Третий</option>
</select>
<p>Скрытый блок</p>
```